# Pop out automatically disappear after some seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup) on how to make a popout on click in Javascript, however I am trying to alter it a bit so when it's clicked on it should automatically disappear again after some seconds... But i can't get it to work, i tried to set the animation to

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
0% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity:1 ;}
100%{opacity:0;}
}
```

It dissapears but it still comes back again... why is that?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 3s;
    animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    50% {opacity:1 ;}
 100%{opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    50% {opacity:1 ;}
 100%{opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the default state of `.popup .show` to `opacity: 0` because after the animation runs it will return to the default state you define.

```
.popup .show {
    opacity: 0; /* add this */
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 3s;
    animation: fadeIn 3s;
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 3s;
    animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    50% {opacity:1 ;}
 100%{opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    50% {opacity:1 ;}
 100%{opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fade in should be:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
0% {opacity: 0;}
100%{opacity: 1;}
}
```

By setting it back to 0 at 100% like you do, it does a fadeIn / fadeOut animation

EDIT: Sorry I got the question wrong

Comment: huh? Then it doesn't fade out aswell? .-.

Comment: _it should automatically disappear again after some seconds_ I think he wants it to go back to a invisible state. Please re-read the question

Comment: Yes that is true, however i want it to go fadeout without me having to click on it. sorry if my question is unclear:)